# What is Sublime Text doing when I save a file?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

I was watching files with [fsnotify](https://github.com/howeyc/fsnotify) which is a Go library, and I found there are many events triggered when I save a file.

Why does Sublime Text do so much?

```
2013/12/17 20:46:25 event: "parser.go": MODIFY
2013/12/17 20:46:25 event: ".subl317.tmp": MODIFY
2013/12/17 20:46:25 event: "parser.go": DELETE
2013/12/17 20:46:25 event: ".subl317.tmp": DELETE
2013/12/17 20:46:25 event: "parser.go": CREATE
2013/12/17 20:46:27 event: "parser.go": MODIFY
2013/12/17 20:46:27 event: ".subl3aa.tmp": MODIFY
2013/12/17 20:46:28 event: ".subl28d.tmp": CREATE
2013/12/17 20:46:28 event: ".subl28d.tmp": MODIFY
2013/12/17 20:46:28 event: "parser.go": MODIFY
2013/12/17 20:46:28 event: ".subl3aa.tmp": MODIFY
2013/12/17 20:46:28 event: "parser.go": DELETE
2013/12/17 20:46:28 event: ".subl3aa.tmp": DELETE
```

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Sublime Text 3 (which I assume you're using) uses atomic saves by default (it can be disabled by setting `"atomic_save": false` in your user settings), which means it creates temp files and then overwrites the original file (and deletes the temp file) on save. See [this thread](https://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=11531) on the Sublime forums for a little more info, especially the reply from `jps` (Sublime's author) on its disadvantages.

Basically, atomic saving is useful because if anything were to happen during saving you (theoretically) shouldn't end up with a corrupted original file. Downsides include potential loss of file metadata (although Sublime uses native OS X and Windows APIs to prevent that), unexpected behavior in directories with nonstandard permissions (for example, they allow modification of existing files, but not the creation of new ones), and issues when saving to some network drives or services like Dropbox, which I've experienced personally.

### ***EDIT***

Since I originally answered this, I've come across a number of questions where post-save file-watching compilers/preprocessors like LESS/SASS/SCSS, Guard, etc. were not doing their thing because the original file they were watching had been deleted by atomic saving, then created again, but they weren't watching it any more. It can also severely affect file I/O speed when working with network filesystems, SSHFS in particular. It's a good idea in theory, but it can wreak havoc if you don't know it's there or what it's doing, so if you'll be doing any kind of work on networked/shared/watched files, it's probably best just to turn it off. Just go to **`Preferences -> Settings-User`** and add this line

```js
"atomic_save": false
```

to the end (the file has to be valid [JSON](http://www.json.org), so make sure there's a comma `,` after the previous line). Save, and you're good to go!

### ***UPDATE***

As of Sublime Text 3 Build 3072, `atomic_save` is now disabled by default! If you are a registered user, you can download the latest development build [here](http://www.sublimetext.com/3dev). This feature has not been ported to the public beta (currently Build 3065), but hopefully a new version will be released soon. As of Feb/March 2015, Sublime's development pace has picked up substantially, with a number of new features having been added. Once the bugs have been worked out of them, a new public version should be forthcoming.

**update to the UPDATE**

`"atomic_save": false` is (as of March 2015) now in the default settings from Build 3080 and higher.

Comment: I was experiencing random failures using jsx watch where it complained about missing files/directories.  Turning atomic saves off seems to do the trick, thanks! http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tooling-integration.html

Comment: I had the same problem as described above for file-watching compilers/preprocessors like LESS/SASS/SCSS, but with the Plone library sauna.reload. Setting "atomic_save" to false solves the reloading problem. Thanks!

Comment: I experienced a problem with lsyncd on saving files on OSX. The saved file just was not transferred to the remote server. Disabling atomic_save solved  this issue.

Comment: this didn't solve the problem, im using dev channel build 3095. and it adds x permissions to the file I save. I am coding in windows and the files are being accessed through samba.

Comment: @kapitanluffy that's a different issue than what's being described here

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't notice that. I was actually planning to comment on an issue that's linked to this one. @MattDMo

Comment: this was helpful in understanding why npm packages `nodemon` and `pm2 --watch` were not playing nice with docker containers with volume mounts

Answer (score 2):

If it is related to **name.php** file,and after saving you are getting another **name.php-tmp** file, then you can **remove PHPTools** package From *Preference ->Browse Packages*, It will be rectified.