# Sublime Text 3 seems to block .LESS file from getting compiled by WinLess

Tags: sublimetext3

Until today, I had been using Sublime Text 2 and WinLess software to compile .LESS files to CSS. The files got compiled automatically when I saved a file.

However since I upgraded to Sublime Text 3, automatic compiling has stopped. To see if its issue with WinLess, I tried editing the .less file in NotePad, and the automated compilation work.

So I am assuming Sublime Text3 seems to be locking file or something.

Anyone faced this or have any ideas to debug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the following to your Preferences (`Preferences -> Settings-User`):

```
"atomic_save": false
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20634684/1426065) and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20639093/1426065) below for an explanation of what Sublime is doing behind the scenes when `atomic_save` is true (the default setting). Temp files are created and destroyed, and the original file is deleted and recreated. This could easily mess with a LESS compiler just looking for a simple file modification. Using the `"atomic_save": false` setting also dramatically decreases save time on some network setups.

Comment: Wow, that did it. Thanks mate. Really appreciate your help. Another question though (after reading your answers on the other thread). Has this feature been introduced only since version 3? Is there any major side affects after disabling?

Comment: @HarishChouhan - yes, this was introduced in ST3. Theoretically, if something were to happen to the file during saving (such as another process trying to modify it) you could end up with a corrupted file if `atomic_save` is true. However, the chances of that are very slight, especially if you only have the file open in one place at a time, and you know other processes aren't using it.