# Guard does not recognize Sublime Text 3 file changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sublimetext, guard

Currently, I am testing Sublime Text 3 (ST3) for my Rails projects.
But I have an issue with guard.

Guard does not recognize any file changes made with ST3.
When I edit and save a file with `nano`, `vi`, ... everything works perfect.

I found an old post (2011) describing this behavior http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/41760-atomic-file-saves-to-ensure-file-integrity/

Is there a way to get guard running? Guard with the ST3 package https://github.com/cyphactor/sublime_guard does not work, too.

I use Rails 4, Ruby 2.1, Guard 2.5.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your user preferences file (`Preferences -> Settings-User`), add the following line:

```json
"atomic_save": false
```

For more information on what's going on, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20634684/1426065) and my answer below. Basically, atomic save can delete and recreate files, and has been known to mess up file watchers like LESS/SASS/SCSS, so it's not surprising that Guard is not working either. Hopefully, turning atomic saving off will solve the problem.