# SVN shows unmodified files as modified

Tags: svn, vim, diff, sublimetext3

I have the following problem:

**Case 1**: I checkout a svn repo, open a file with Sublime or gedit or nano and I save it without doing anything. When I do a svn diff on that file a bunch of lines appear as if they were modified. I revert to base.

**Case 2**: I open the same file with vim or notepad (on wine) save the file without doing any modifications and svn diff is empty as it should.

Has anyone experienced such a behavior? It's really annoying and I can't create a proper patch.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Possible problem in line endings.
Try find in Sublime/gedit option to not convert line endings or every time force save with correct line ending.

Comment: Nope doesn't seam to fix it. The thing is that for some files it does this and for others it does not, I have checked svn props and found noting there. Here is a sample code of how it looks:
`-            if (!is_null($row['fh_delete'])){
-                $v = $row['fh_delete'];
+            if (!is_null($row['fh_delete'])){
+                $v = $row['fh_delete'];
             }`

Also checked to see that there are no trailing spaces

Comment: You were right, the problem was with line endings. The only thing is that I don't know of a setting which makes sublime to leave line endings alone

Answer (score 1):

Open your user preferences (`Preferences -> Settings-User`) and add the following option:

```
"atomic_save": false
```

Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20634684/1426065) and my answer below for a full explanation of what atomic saving is, and how it can interfere with a number of external programs, including (I suppose) version control systems like Subversion. Essentially, when `"atomic_save"` is `true` (the default in Sublime Text 3), saving a file creates some temp files, deletes the original file, then renames a temp file to the original's name. SVN is probably picking this up, and is showing the whole file as changed, when in fact you haven't done anything to it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I've tried this setting but it does not seam to work.