# Is there any way to improve sshfs speed on amazon aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, remote-access, sublimetext3, sshfs

My ping to the AWS instance is on the level of 50ms and cat'ing files through the ssh takes way less than second, but when I mount directory using sshfs and open it using SublimeText3/Gedit lags are greater than 10 seconds. 
1. Is there anything I could do to reduce those lags? 
2. Why it works like that? 
3. Are some better tools for remote file editing?

My ssh config:

```
Host myinstance
  HostName ********
  User ec2-user
  IdentityFile ~/idfile
  Compression no
  Ciphers arcfour
  ServerAliveInterval 15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a first step, I'd suggest adding this line to your settings (`Preferences -> Settings-User`):

```
"atomic_save": false
```

and see if that does the trick. [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20639093/1426065) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20634684/1426065) has some more details behind why this works, but basically what Sublime is doing with `atomic_save` enabled is creating new temp files and deleting the original file, then renaming the temp back to the original's name. This leads to a very significant increase in traffic over the connection, and if the server on the other side of the pipe is a little bit laggy anyway, it can really slow down Sublime.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your solution + removing GitGutter from ST3 fixed the situation.