# Sublime Text 3 on mac save read only, is not requesting password

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

I'm trying to save a system file with ST3, /etc/hosts but it throws an error. On another mac machine it ask me for the password and saves normally, but on this new installation it just show this error:

```
Unable to save ...
Error: ... is readonly px_administrator_copy_file(/tmp/.sublbca.tmp, ...)
```

Any idas why is not asking for sudo password?

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you can try. First, try opening the file with `sudo` in the first place. To do this, you'll need to place a symlink to the `subl` shortcut in `/usr/bin`:

```
sudo ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/bin/subl
```

Then, you can just run

```
sudo subl /etc/hosts
```

enter your password, and continue as normally.

Second, I'd [highly recommend](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20634684/1426065) setting

```js
"atomic_save": false
```

in your user preferences (**`Sublime Text -> Preferences -> Settings-User`**). The error you are getting is on a temp file created by atomic saving, and as I explain in the linked answer above, file metadata can get altered or lost when using this "feature", so it's best to just turn it off.