# guard-livereload stopped working

Tags: rack, guard, livereload

Since merging in my co-worker's changes this morning, `guard-livereload` has stopped working. The javascript is being injected into the page, and guard does detect my browser, but no matter what files I modify, it simply does not reload whatsoever.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/henrebotha/61cd357a547aaa33a75c) is my console output today, with `livereload` not working. Note that there is just zero output after detecting the browser - unlike other questions on stackoverflow, where `livereload` claims to be reloading but does not do anything. [Here](https://gist.github.com/henrebotha/6a8927b5e02d2af99fef) is my console output from the last time I was at work, when it did function correctly. The annoying thing is that `ui.css.scss` is the file I'm modifying now as well! My `guardfile` has not changed, I've checked.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/henrebotha/5edae6c4f07b3dbfb219) is my `bundle install` output from this morning (my co-worker updated a bunch of gems). I'm using [`rack-livereload`](https://github.com/johnbintz/rack-livereload) in lieu of a browser extension.

Any advice?

UPDATE: I've tried using the Livereload Chrome extension, but I get exactly the same (lack of) output, so I don't believe `rack-livereload` to be the culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution, in part thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20639093/1966418).

It turns out Sublime Text 3's atomic save feature is what was preventing LiveReload from detecting changes to Sass files. Why it worked before a certain commit is beyond me...

Simply add `"atomic_save": false` to your Sublime settings to avert this.

Comment: FYI atomic_save is disabled by default as of build 3080 http://www.sublimetext.com/3

Answer (score 1):

Just to add an alternative solution - for me this was because I'd upgraded to rails 4.2 and changed my asset file names from .css.scss to .scss as per the recommendation in the logs.

Of course, when I checked my Guardfile I was still watching for .css files:

```
... (css|js|html|png|jpg) ... { |m| "/assets/#{m[3]}" }
```

A simple change from watching for css to scss like so:

```
... (scss|js|html|png|jpg) ... { |m| "/assets/#{m[3]}" }
```

and all fixed!