# Sublime Text 3 File Attributes

Tags: sublimetext3

Is anybody experiencing a file suddenly changed to hidden after editing? I get this problem all the time with sublime text 3 but when I changed to sublime text 2 it doesn't happen.

**INFO:** The file is under a shared folder from the server.  All are OK when files are edited locally

Answer (score 3):

Sublime text 3 has some big problems with mounted file systems. This is partially due to the new `atomic_save` setting. This [sublime forum post](https://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=15377) seems to imply that your problem is caused by atomic save.

Try putting this **in your user or project settings**:

```
"atomic_save": false
```

It seems that when a file is saved with atomic save, a new file is created with the hidden attribute, then the original file is deleted and the temporary hidden file is renamed to replace the original. When you are using a shared filesystem, the hidden attribute must never get reset.

Comment: Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20634684/1426065) and the associated answer for what exactly is going on, if you're interested.