# Error while saving .less with SublimeText 3

Tags: css, less, sublimetext3

I get this error when i try saving .less file with sublime text. I just started using .less today so 
maybe it is my mistake.

[image: less_error]

EDIT: this is my current piece of code:

```
//VARIABLES
@color1: blue;
@text_color: black;
@page_background_color: white;

h1 {
    color: @color1;
}

#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
}
```

Comment: Do you have write permissions in that location?

Comment: I do have all permissions as I checked in the security properties

Comment: Is it possible to save other type of files on the same folder or a new .less file?

Comment: What version of ST3 are you using? Make sure you have upgraded to Build 3083 if you're using the public beta, or Build 3095 if using the dev builds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are most likely using a version of Sublime Text 3 before Build 3072, or for some other reason you have `"atomic_save"` enabled in your preferences. It is *highly* recommended to upgrade to the latest versions when they are released, as they include many bugfixes and new features. Prior to 3072, `"atomic_save"` was enabled by default, which caused [all sorts of problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20639093/1426065). It was disabled in 3072 (in the [dev builds](http://sublimetext.com/3dev)) and 3080 in the [public beta](http://sublimetext.com/3).

If you suspect it has been enabled in your system, follow these steps to disable it:

1. Open your user preferences (**`Preferences -> Settings-User`**)
2. Check to see if the `"atomic_save"` option is present. If so, change it to `false`.
3. If it is not present, add the following line (adding commas `,` as necessary to maintain valid JSON):

   ```js
   "atomic_save": false
   ```
4. Save the file, close it, then restart Sublime for good measure.

Comment: Thanks, i've upgraded to version 3083 and now it seems everything works fine